# how can I add the values to the key when read from file and add into dictionary

Tags: python

I am new in the python and I have question 
I have text file this contains some information like  Jacob, Mason, 18 and James, David, 20
how can I read the first coulme and add before word first name the example for output 
first name : Jacob last name: Mason: age: 18
first name: James last name: David: age: 20
I do not it should add to the set or dictionary
can give an example how can I do it in python
I hope my questions are clear 
and my title is correct

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you are trying to read from a file and then put the data into a dictionary. I shall assume the dictionary key to be the name of the individual e.g. Jacob Mason data shall be stored as key = JasonMason and value = 18

Then probably something like this would do:

```
file = open("data.txt", "r")
```

data = {}

with open("data.txt", "r") as file:
    content = file.readlines()

```
content = [x.strip(",|\n") for x in content]

for x in content:
    a = x.split(',')
    data[str(a[0]) + str(a[1])] = str(a[2])

print(data)
```

The results will be as follow:

> {'JacobMason': '18', 'JamesDavid': '20'}

Comment: can the results like this First Name:- Jacobson , age:- 18 and the word the first name add in the code is not in the file and also age